# Angular Js : Validate form field on user input

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a form field. The problem is that i want to display the errors when user interact with the field.
I am using the below code :

```
<form class="" name="myForm" novalidate>
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="user-icon" name="fname" ng-model="user.fname" required>
        <div ng-show="myForm.fname.$dirty && myForm.fname.$error.required">First Name is required.</div>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="user-icon" name="lname" ng-model="user.lname">
        <div ng-show="myForm.lname.$error.required">Last Name is required.</div>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="email-icon" name="email" ng-model="user.email">
        <div ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</div>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Password" class="password-icon" name="password" ng-model="user.password">
        <div ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required">Password is required.</div>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="password-icon" name="conf_password" ng-model="user.conf_password">
        <div ng-show="myForm.conf_password.$error.required">Confirm Password is required.</div>


        </form>
```

But the code is not working. Please correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You forget to add `required`

and add `novalidate` in your form

Try like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="user-icon" name="fname" ng-model="user.fname" required>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it's still not working. I don't want to use HTML required

Comment: please provide your full html code .. it'll be better if you can provide plunkr

Comment: Don't forget to add form name `myForm`